# How to model for querying multiple column efficiently?

Tags: python, cassandra, model, denormalization

I am humbly coming here to look for help, as I am currently puzzled by some aspects of Cassandra modelling and its implications.

I understood that ideally, there would be a table for each column that we want to filter by. (I met some issues with secondary index not being updated).

So let's take an example:

```py
class Pet(Model):
    pet_id = columns.UUID(partition_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = columns.Text()
    age = colmuns.Text()

class PetByName(Model):
    pet_id = columns.UUID(default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = columns.Text(partition_key=True)
    age = colmuns.Text()

class PetByAge(Model):
    pet_id = columns.UUID(default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = columns.Text()
    age = colmuns.Text(partition_key=True)
```

Queries are then simple if I want to query for one attribute for example:

```py
PetByName.filter(name="kitty")
```

So my first question is: How do we do if we want, for example, to query for a pet named "kitty" and aged of "25 years".

Right now, I have a quite cumbersome implementation where I do two queries, and I then loop over the results to do a manual intersection on the `pet_id` attribute.

But in my head, there should be an implementation/type of batch queries that would run both queries at the same time and then merge the result sets based on an operator like `intersect`.

Any help, opinion, piece of advice is warmly welcomed.

Thank you for reading, and have a lovely day!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to query either by name or by age your table structure should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE pet_by_name (
     id uuid,
     name text,
     age integer,
     PRIMARY KEY (name, age)
);
```

In this case age is a clustering key. This table supports queries by name only or by name AND age.